# how to add a custom meta box to WYSIWYG editor tab

Tags: wordpress

In the WYSIWYG editor we had `visual` and `text` as two tabs. I need to add an another tab with a custom meta box and WYSIWYG editor in that.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tQiJ.png)

I tried many things, but I am unable to add the custom meta box with WYSIWYG editor as a tab to default WYSIWYG editor.

```
    define('WYSIWYG_META_BOX_ID', 'my-editor');
define('WYSIWYG_EDITOR_ID', 'myeditor'); //Important for CSS that this is different
define('WYSIWYG_META_KEY', 'Telugucontent');

add_action('admin_init', 'wysiwyg_register_meta_box');
function wysiwyg_register_meta_box(){
        add_meta_box(WYSIWYG_META_BOX_ID, __('WYSIWYG Meta Box', 'wysiwyg'), 'wysiwyg_render_meta_box', 'vaults');
}
function wysiwyg_render_meta_box(){

        global $post;

        $meta_box_id = 'my-editor';
        $editor_id = 'myeditor';

        //Add CSS jQuery goodness to make this work like the original WYSIWYG
        echo "
                <style type='text/css'>
                        #$meta_box_id #edButtonHTML, #$meta_box_id #edButtonPreview {background-color: #F1F1F1; border-color: #DFDFDF #DFDFDF #CCC; color: #999;}
                        #$meta_box_id #$editor_id{width:100%;}
                        #$meta_box_id #editorcontainer{background:#fff !important;}
                        #$meta_box_id #$editor_id_fullscreen{display:none;}
                </style>

                <script type='text/javascript'>
                        jQuery(function($){
                                $('#$meta_box_id #editor-toolbar > a').click(function(){
                                        $('#$meta_box_id #editor-toolbar > a').removeClass('active');
                                        $(this).addClass('active');
                                });

                                if($('#$meta_box_id #edButtonPreview').hasClass('active')){
                                        $('#$meta_box_id #ed_toolbar').hide();
                                }

                                $('#$meta_box_id #edButtonPreview').click(function(){
                                        $('#$meta_box_id #ed_toolbar').hide();
                                });

                                $('#$meta_box_id #edButtonHTML').click(function(){
                                        $('#$meta_box_id #ed_toolbar').show();
                                });
                        });
                </script>
        ";

        //Create The Editor
        $content = get_post_meta($post->ID, WYSIWYG_META_KEY, true);
        the_editor($content, $editor_id);

        //Clear The Room!
        echo "<div style='clear:both; display:block;'></div>";
}
add_action('save_post', 'wysiwyg_save_meta');
function wysiwyg_save_meta(){

        $editor_id = WYSIWYG_EDITOR_ID;
        $meta_key = WYSIWYG_META_KEY;

        if(isset($_REQUEST[$editor_id]))
                update_post_meta($_REQUEST['post_ID'], WYSIWYG_META_KEY, $_REQUEST[$editor_id]);
                update_post_meta($_REQUEST['post_ID'], 'gmet_textarea', $_REQUEST['gmet_textarea']);

}
```

with the other custom meta box i saved the data of textarea showed in that tab

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! You say you have tried many things, but what have you tried? We can't help you if we don't know where you're at with it.

Comment: i have worked on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/122922/how-to-add-a-new-tab-to-page-editor/122948#122948

for this how to add a wysiwyg editor

Comment: What code have you used though? We need to see your code, then we can tell you why it's not working.

Comment: updated the metabox code how to add this in tab